# Build a NN able to handle multiple-input and multiple-output

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm trying to create a NN, which has as input a matrix of players (n) with some specific features (m). This is a n * m matrix. My idea is to select a subset of these players using a neural network. However my idea is to give as input, in the input node, each single row ( so a vector (1,m)) and as output node have a value between 0 and 1 for each starting node ((n,1)). Ho can I build a possible NN ?

Could you help me to define Input shape and Output dimension ?

```
data = np.random.rand(29,43)
```

I want to select for example k<29 elements from this beginning dataset.

Comment: Your question is oriented and ambiguous. Are you asking for a neural network to select the 29 first (or top) cells from a matrix? Is that it? If so, you do not need such a fancy device: there is probably a [numpy method](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/index.html) for this. If by `k<29` you mean something more specific, please, be specific

Comment: No, I want to select k (<29) elements using a NN, giving as input information all the feature vector in each node of the net. Is more clear ? My problem is to define input dimension and output dimension.

Comment: For example, I have a dataset of 29 houses, and each house has 41 features. Now I want to select through a NN the best 10 houses. My  idea is to give as input in NN each house in a single node (29 beginning nodes) and finally put as output node the same dimension (29) of the input to have a value between 0-1 and finally selecting the most promising 10.

Comment: OK. The "*most promising 10*" based on what? You want to train a NN to learn the most relevant features. How is your training set structured? For the only way you could answer a question like "*how my model' output dimension should be?*" is : just look to the data you will compare your models predictions with

Comment: That being said, [datascience.stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place ot discuss these issues (you won't get that many "data dudes" here)

Comment: Ok @zar3bski. I do not have any labels but just trying to work with RL.